# What tag should I use for Modbus?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [What's the role of Negative Acknowledge (NAK) in Modbus?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39453/whats-the-role-of-negative-acknowledge-nak-in-modbus)

There's no tag referring to Modbus, and I'm unable to create it because I'm still a beginner in this community. I used the tag *troubleshooting*, which is not very accurate in this case. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find a tag for Modbus. On a network, Modbus rides on top of TCP or UDP, meaning is is a protocol above OSI layer-4, which, unfortunately, means it is off-topic on Network Engineering. Even the title of the link you posted claims its an application protocol, not a network protocol.

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of the [Help Center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help) has a list of topics that are allowed, and a list of topic that are not allowed.